# Pandas parse issue with missing zeros after thousands seperator in csv-file

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

Given a csv file with the following content

```
actual; shouldbe
1,200;  1200
1,2;    1200
12;     12
```

I want to read in the content in a way that both columns have equal values. The problem is that there are no trailing zeros after the thousands seperator

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, sep=';', thousands=',')
```

leads to

```
    actual  shouldbe
0   1200    1200
1   12  1200
2   12  12
```

I hope the problem is clear. I don't have an idea how to clean my data, either in pandas or any other python and non-python tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: Against expectations, I have found my naive solution to be the fastest (including faster than [@RomanPekar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41187920/5276797)'s solution).

---

**Fastest solution**: naive solution

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, dtype='object')  # to load as string

def fix(string):
    l = string.split(',')
    if len(l) > 1 and len(l[-1]) < 3:
        l[-1] = l[-1] + (3-len(l[-1])) * '0'
    return int(''.join(l))

df['actual'].apply(fix)
```

---

**Slowest solution**: vectorized solution:

```
missing = (3 - df['actual'].str.split(',').str.get(-1).str.len())
pad = missing.mul(pd.Series(len(missing) * ['0']))
pad = np.where(df['actual'].str.contains(','), pad, '')
pd.to_numeric((df['actual'].str.replace(',', '') + pad))
```

It simply does what the naive method does, except in vectorized form.

---

**Performance comparison**:

```
%timeit df['actual'].apply(fix)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.48 ms per loop

%timeit df.actual.apply(lambda x: ''.join(k if i==0 else k.ljust(3, '0') for i,k in enumerate(x.split(',')))).astype(int)
100 loops, best of 3: 8.34 ms per loop

%timeit pd.to_numeric((df['actual'].str.replace(',', '') + np.where(df['actual'].str.contains(','), (3 - df['actual'].str.split(',').str.get(-1).str.len()).mul(pd.Series(len(df) * ['0'])), '')))
100 loops, best of 3: 12.6 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thank you! Since In my opinion your naive solution is the most readable I accepted your solution. By the way, your speed test also holds true for my "real" data (~9000 entries)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure it could be done without some data cleaning after loading:

```
>>> s=u"""actual;shouldbe
... 1,200;1200
... 1,001,21;  1001210
... 1,2;   1200
... 12;   12"""
>>> df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep=";")
>>> df['result'] = df.actual.apply(lambda x: ''.join(k if i==0 else k.ljust(3, '0') for i,k in enumerate(x.split(','))))
>>> df
     actual  shouldbe   result
0     1,200      1200     1200
1  1,001,21   1001210  1001210
2       1,2      1200     1200
3        12        12       12
```